# SPARQL Query using FILTER

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have some question on the way of using `FILTER`
When I used the query as below in the DBPedia SPARQL Endpoint, 1 result was retrieved.
However, if I take  `FILTER (   langMatches(lang(?sl),'en') && langMatches(lang(?ol),'en') )` off from the query, then, there is nothing retrieved.
I think there should be more results because `FILTER` wasn't used.

How can this be possible?

SPARQL Endpoint : dbpedia.org/sparql

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?s ?sl (<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/depiction> as ?p) ?o ?ol

WHERE {
  ?s rdfs:label ?sl . 
  ?s <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/depiction> ?o .
  ?o rdfs:label ?ol .

  FILTER (   langMatches(lang(?sl),'en') && langMatches(lang(?ol),'en') )  <------- this part
} 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Just a note:  the comment character in SPARQL is `#`.  We can copy and paste your query if you do `# <---- this part` instead of just `<---- this part`.

Answer (score 2):

This is strange, and I do see the results that you're talking about.  You've got a web-service that you can run queries against, and it's easy to modify the query a bit to get more information about what's happening.  First, let see how many results there are in total (without the filter):

```
select (count(*) as ?nResults) where {
  ?s rdfs:label ?sl . 
  ?s <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/depiction> ?o .
  ?o rdfs:label ?ol .
}
```

> 24

Now, how many are left if we take only those pairs with English labels?

```
select (count(*) as ?nResults) where {
  ?s rdfs:label ?sl . 
  ?s <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/depiction> ?o .
  ?o rdfs:label ?ol .
  filter ( langMatches(lang(?sl),'en') && langMatches(lang(?ol),'en') )
}
```

> 1

That's promising, since we'd expect the number to *decrease* when we add additional constraints.  Those numbers are also small enough that we don't need to worry about the limit, and we can look at the results directly.  First, for the unfiltered results:

```
select * where {
  ?s rdfs:label ?sl . 
  ?s <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/depiction> ?o .
  ?o rdfs:label ?ol .
}
```

When I run this query, I'd *expect* to get back 24 result rows, as the first query suggested.  When I run it, though, I don't actually get any results.  This query seems to take quite a while, and it may be that we're running into some timeouts.  In any case, something strange is going on. On to the filtered query:

```
select * where {
  ?s rdfs:label ?sl . 
  ?s <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/depiction> ?o .
  ?o rdfs:label ?ol .
  filter ( langMatches(lang(?sl),'en') && langMatches(lang(?ol),'en') )
}
```

There's just one result, and it's got these values:

```
s  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Franz_Kruckenberg>
sl "Franz Kruckenberg"@en
o  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Schienenzeppelin>
ol "Schienenzeppelin"@en
```

Since the `count(*)` query in the unfiltered case gives 24, I think that there's something going on here that's not quite right.  It might be a time limit though, in which case you might need to download data locally and run your query locally.  If it's some other kind of bug, though, you might want to get on the DBpedia mailing list and ask them.

Running some related queries doesn't help things too much.  E.g., if you just ask for things that have depictions that have labels, you only get a few results, and they're all about the same resource (Frank Kruckenberg):

```
select * where {
  ?s <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/depiction> [ rdfs:label ?dl ]
}
```

```
dl                      s
---------------------------------------------------------------------
"Schienenzeppelin"@de   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Franz_Kruckenberg
"Schienenzeppelin"@en   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Franz_Kruckenberg
"Schienenzeppelin"@fr   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Franz_Kruckenberg
"Schienenzeppelin"@it   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Franz_Kruckenberg
"シーネンツェッペリン"@ja   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Franz_Kruckenberg
"Schienenzeppelin"@pl   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Franz_Kruckenberg
"Рельсовый Цеппелин"@ru http://dbpedia.org/resource/Franz_Kruckenberg
"Schienenzeppelin"@sv   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Franz_Kruckenberg
```

Comment: The question already says *how many* results are being retrieved in each case, doesn't it (1 and 0, respectively)?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper My mistake;  the question does say 1 and none.  I've removed that bit from the answer.